# Mysql loop over Month and split records

Tags: java, mysql, spring

my table has a TIMESTAMP start_time and TIMESTAMP end_time to record a continuous work.

But I have to make some statistics for each month and specified by date.

Currently my table is:

```
name  |  starttime  | endtime
-----------------------------
A     |  2017-03-16 | 2017-03-18
-----------------------------
B     |  2017-03-16 | 2017-03-16
```

and the expect result is:

```
Date  |  name  |  starttime  | endtime
---------------------------------------
16    |   A    |  2017-03-16 |
---------------------------------------
16    |   B    |  2017-03-16 | 2017-03-16
---------------------------------------
17    |   A    |             |
---------------------------------------
18    |   A    |             | 2017-03-18
---------------------------------------
```

The logic is easy, but I failed to iterate the list by date, and split and resort those data. I am using Spring boot + mysql.
Thank you.

Comment: Please show what you tried and what the error/problem is.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the mysql function , such as:

```
day('2016-03-31 10:20:37'),
month("2016-03-31 10:20:37"),
date("2016-03-31 10:20:37")
```

,http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-day-function.php